# jQuery - Get element where id not like search string

Tags: jquery

I'm still learning jQuery and I'm able to search for all elements on a page where an attribute is "like" a text string. (using something like `$(a[href*=pdf])` to get all PDF links)

Is there anyway to search for all elements where the attribute is **not** like a query string?

I'm wanting to use this so I can check for any links that point to an external domain and to do something special with them

Comment: I'm wanting to use this so I can check for any links that point to an external domain and to do something special with them

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick replies and supplying such a simple solution. It worked great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:not` like this

```
$('a:not([href*=pdf])')
```

See example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gNFQS/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:not` to effectively invert your search:

`$("a:not([href*=pdf])")`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nYaBS/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in [**:not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('a:not([href*=pdf])')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$("a:not([href*=pdf])").doFunction()
```

The selector has a varity of not features which you can see at

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/